# Punctuation for referring to a question

Tags: punctuation, questions, quotations, question-mark

Is either of these an incorrect or nonstandard way to refer to a question mid sentence? Or are both of them okay?

> Our experiment set out to answer the question; is running fruit under water an effective way to reduce the number of surface microbes?
>
> Our experiment set out to answer the question, "Is running fruit under water an effective way to reduce the number of surface microbes?"

Comment: "Is *rinsing* fruit..."

Comment: You're only asking about punctuation aren't you? If so then it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence could become correct if you replace the semi-colon with a colon. "Our experiment set out to answer the question: Is running fruit under water an effective way to reduce the number of surface microbes?" In that case, either sentence would be suitable.

Alternately, you could avoid the issue all together by rephrasing it. For example, "Our experiment set out to determine whether running fruit under water is an effective way to reduce the number of surface microbes."

Comment: Not even a semi-colon, just a comma should do.